# How to get the direction of moving object in draggable plugin (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have object (div-box), and it's draggable (I'm using jQuery). How I can get information which direction a visitor moved it? Example: User drag it to left down and I wanna know it, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

how about this?

```
var start,stop;

$("#draggable2").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        start = ui.position.left;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        stop = ui.position.left;
        alert('has moved ' + ((start < stop) ? 'right':'left'))
    }
});​
```

## [crazy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMcYT/)

Comment: That's the gist of it.  Implementation details may vary, but you'll have to remember where the cursor was previously and compare to where it is now.  May also want to check if horizontal change was greater than vertical change to choose between left/right or up/down.

Comment: Well, this is the start of the idea. `ui.position.top` is also available. The OP can deal with it easy.

Answer (score 3):

The original position is built into the ui.helper object..  You can just do:

```
        $('#foo').draggable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var dragged = ui.helper;
                var dragged_data = dragged.data('draggable');
                var direction = (dragged_data.originalPosition.left > dragged.position().left) ? 'left' : 'right';

                console.log(direction);
            }
        });
```

You can do this in the start, drag, or stop event callbacks...

Comment: Do you know how this would with with revert set to true?

Answer (score 1):

There is two answers to this question:

1. get direction in real time, namely no matter the starting position. For that you need to set and use `previousPosition` as follow:

   ```
   $("#draggable").draggable({
       axis: "x",
       start: function(event, ui) {
           this.previousPosition = ui.position;
       },
       drag: function(event, ui) {
           var direction = (this.previousPosition.left > ui.position.left) ? 'left' : 'right';
           alert('moving ' + direction)
       }
   });​
   ```
2. get direction after the drop, therefore using the starting position. For that you need to use the provided `originalPosition` as follow:

   ```
   $("#draggable").draggable({
       axis: "x",
       stop: function(event, ui) {
           var direction = (ui.originalPosition.left > ui.position.left) ? 'left' : 'right';
           alert('has moved ' + direction)
       }
   });​
   ```

**Note:** This code was written for and tested with jQuery 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page, Source code and Demo is available on this website :

http://www.coursesweb.net/jquery/jquery-ui-draggable-drag