# jQuery detect dragging left or right

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I've been looking about the mousemove() and mousedown() methods on the docs @ jQuery's official but didn't managed to come up with a simple solution to listen and do something when the mouse-dragging left/right event happens.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you thinking of touch events?

Comment: Oh no, but sweep moves would be much better to include.

Comment: You could also use jQuery UI's draggable widget, or use mousemove and mousedown as you mentioned. However your question is ambiguous and doesn't show what you've tried.

Comment: I just need to detect if the mouse is dragging (mousedown+mousemove) left or right. Let's say is a fullscreen invisible div, that's really not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious starting place is http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MMcYT/ (from [How to get the direction of moving object in draggable plugin (jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861053/how-to-get-the-direction-of-moving-object-in-draggable-plugin-jquery)) which I think solves your problem

```
var start,stop;

$("#draggable2").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        start = ui.position.left;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        stop = ui.position.left;
        alert('has moved ' + ((start < stop) ? 'rigth':'left'))
    }
});
```

(Credit to @Reigel)